# Can I hack the Telerik RadButton to make a 'Big Icon Button'?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

Here is what a regular `RadButton` might look like:

[image: Regular RadButton]

However, we want a larger button... something that might look like:

[image]

The icon should stay the same. The color and text formatting is probably negotiable, but I really need a 'RadBigButton' kind of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to change the width and height of a RadButton providing that you aren't using using ButtonType="StandardButton". Unfortunately, in your case, it appears as if you are using "Standard Button" and therefore the button height is fixed to 22px and can't be changed.

Since the RadButton was introduced only in the most recent 2010 Q3 release, I'm sure we can expect the addition of new functionality but, for the time being, it isn't there.

The only way to achieve your goal is to use an ImageButton.

Comment: Yeah it seems that is what I will have to do. I was just trying to avoid any graphic design requests. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All the telerik controls can have customized looks by applying your own custom CSS.